# Execute script when select option is changed

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have a html form which includes a dynamically created dorpdown list. The dropdown list contains the names of newsletters which are stored in my MySQL database. What I want the dropdown list to do is: When I select a newsletter an other php script will activate which will take the data from the newsletter in my DB and writes it to a .txt file. The codes I currently have is:

The dropdown list:

```
<?php
    echo "<select id=\"NieuwsbriefSelect\" name=\"show\">"; 
    echo "<option size =30 selected>Select</option>";
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql_result)) 
    { 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) 
    { 
    echo "<option value=\"$row[Titel]\">$row[Titel]</option>"; 
    } 

    } 
    else {
    echo "<option>No Names Present</option>";  
    } 
?>
```

And the write script:

```
<?php
$title = $_REQUEST["show"];
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root'); 
mysql_select_db('NAW') or die (mysql_error()); 
$strSQL = "SELECT Content from NAW.Mail where Titel = '$title' ";

$sql_result = mysql_query($strSQL); 

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);  


$file = 'nieuwsbrief.txt';

$current = $row["Content"];

file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

I do not want the page to redirect to the write script but just to execute it (I hope you get this^^). Is this possible using the HTML onChange Event or do I have to use javascript? Any help would be great and if you have a question about my code just ask in the comments!

***NOTE!***
I know I shouldn't be using Mysql_* and That I am vulnerable to sql injection but that is not the point.

Comment: Well, technically the HTML onChange event IS Javascript. In any case, you could probably do this real easy by invoking a Javascript function when the selected item is changed. In that function, you can then do the call to your PHP script using the apropiate parameters. I know you've already mentioned that you are aware of the fact that you're prone to SQL-Injections this way, but you should really, really keep this in mind while developing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a onchange event on your SELECT option and inside this onchange event, you can redirect to another page with selected item OR do an AJAX call to another PHP script

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you are asking is not possible without JavaScript. **PHP** is a server side language and therefore cannot be run, without a call from the client-side browser. You're best bet would be to use **ajax** in conjunction with the JavaScript onchange event. When the change event occurs, fire an ajax call off to the server to run the script with the selected option. This is the only way to do what you're asking without a page reload or redirect.

Comment: Thnx for your response! I will take a look at AJAX and see how far I get^^